# fabric JS toDataURL is producing large images with iPad browsers.

Tags: ipad, fabricjs

I have created a small website that lets users create a collage of images in frames.  I have no issues with all browsers I have tried...except any browsers on my iPad; both Chrome and Safari.

My call to save the canvas is as follows...

```
var durl = fabCanvas.toDataURL({
   format: 'png',
   multiplier: 1
});
```

The image should come out as follows...


[image]


But instead it is coming out like so...


[image]


These images are not big.  Any reason why it would be doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabricjs supports retina display of your ipad device.
The Canvas is prescaled to give the display higher clarity when watched.
Unfortunately this was not taken in account when exporting to dataUrl.
Lately (less than one month ago) this defect has been corrected on Feb 24 2016 with this 
[commit](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/df1cffaadee9bbc34d9a56f1a43689ef395637ab).

Your code is probably correct, what you have to do is download and build latest version of fabricjs.

Comment: I also had to scale objects in my canvas using code from the answer of this post...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13399901/1384773

Comment: i think it should work out of the box. Would you mind sharing a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: If you would be so kind as to guide me in how to build the latest version of FabricJS and link it to Fiddle, I'd be glad to.  Honestly I had some issues building the correct version.  
I have been using ver. 1.6.0-rc.1 b/c I needed function calcTransformMatrix() which was missing in prior versions.  When I built the latest github repo, my version became 1.5.0, and that was not good.  I ended up adding the changes of your commit into my own version (1.6.0-rc 1).  Sorry if this sounds like a mess, but I'm not too good with github versioning.